# Call next iteration after each callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say I've got the following code,

```
function someFunction(){
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10){
        someAsyncProcess(someField, function(err, data){
            i++;
            // i want the next iteration of the while loop to occur after this
        }
    }
}
```

The someAsyncProcess runs, and increments 'i'.

However, due to the async nature of JavaScript, the while loop runs thousands of times before i = 10. What if I want the while loop to run exactly 10 times. What if I want the while loop to execute the code inside only after the callback function has finished executing.

Is it possible to do this without a setTimeout function?

Please note that I am still relatively new to JavaScript so if I incorrectly used any jargon, correct me.

Comment: `while` is synchronous. You cannot make it wait until an asynchronous process is done. You cannot use a `while` loop in this case.

Comment: Any alternatives?

Comment: Recursion, recursion with promises, rxjs

Comment: *"due to the async nature of JavaScript"* Javascript is not inherently asynchronous. It has no "asynchronous nature" - *some* functions are asynchronous. If you look at it this way, you don't want a `while` loop. What you really want is call your asynchronous function 10 times. Now combine that with the fact that all work you want to be done after an asynchronous function is finished needs to be done in its callback.

Answer (score 5):

`while` is synchronous. You cannot make it wait until an asynchronous process is done. You cannot use a `while` loop in this case.

Instead you can put your code in a function and call the function itself again if the condition is met.

Example:

```
function someFunction() {
    var i = 0;
    function step() {
        if (i < 10) {
            someAsyncProcess(someField, function(err, data) {
                i++;
                step();
            });
        }
    }
    step();
}
```

There are quite a few libraries out there that provide ready-made solutions for this. You might also want to look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in general.

Comment: This will call  async function in intial loop,  if the i value is more than 10

Comment: @Sajan: Sure, but `i` is initialized to `0` here, which is smaller than `10`.

Comment: Thats okey, but he is looking for a while loop alternative, the 'i' value can be anything,  so the value should check first before calling the function

Comment: @Sajan: They are also initializing `i` with `0` in their example. But sure, if the value comes from somewhere it needs to be checked first. It shouldn't be too hard for someone to adapt the example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [node package q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) which will help you return promises. You can achieve the same in the following manner using q.

```
var q = require('q');
function someFunction(){

    var promises = []    
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        promises.push(function() {
            i++;
            //write code here for using current value of i
        })
    }
    return q.all(promises);
}
```

You can call someFunction() as below

```
someFunction().then(function(arrayOfResponseFromEachPromiseFunction) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfResponseFromEachPromiseFunction, null, 4));
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
}).done();
```

Please rectify if you find any syntax error. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use replace while loop Iteration with function recursion

```
function someFunction() {
    var i = 0;
    (function asyncWhile() { 
        if (i < 10) {
            someAsyncProcess(someField, function(err, data) {
                //You code here
                i++;
                asyncWhile(); 
            });
        }
    })(); //auto invoke
}
```